# During voice call, Jabber quites unexpectedly

Tags: xmpp, cisco

During calls, cisco jabber will quit unexpectedly. I get an error report from apple showing the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y04F3.png

This started to happen with the older Jabber version I about 1 month ago, and after installing the newer version 14, it continues to happen randomly throughout the day during my calls.

I'd appreciate anyones help here please.

Answer (score 0):

check the headset settings, this sounds like some settings were changed on the headset and not really jabber related.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).